# Is there a simple HTTP(S) library that doesn't rely on WiFi?

Tags: arduino-ide, library, gsm, http, core-libraries

I'm trying to implement a Mobile Network (only) for the ESP32 using Arduino IDE. So to be able to connect to website up/download files etc. I need to be able to handle various HTTP PUT/GET/POST requests. However, the available libraries seem to always rely on additional WiFi related libraries. I don't want to have to load those as well, as they are quire bloated and not needed for my use scenario.

What options do I have for minimalist HTTP request libraries that does not rely on WiFi or BT or ETH?

Comment: do you have some library over 'Mobile Network' or only AT commands?

Comment: Only AT commands. So now I have to manually construct the request/response with strings, which is a real PITA.

Comment: I don't know about mobile network Arduino library with Server implementation. it would require a public IP address so not many would use it

Comment: I'm not implementing a server, just a connecting client to download files (to the ESP).

Comment: sorry. then you can use TinyGSM. https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM

Comment: @Juraj That look promising. How do you import that library into the IDE?

Comment: is it not in Library Manager?

Comment: My bad! I have no idea why I missed it the other day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The TinyGSM library implements Arduino networking Client base class over GSM modem's AT commands. The library is available in Library Manager.
[image]